# ODM Annotation : What is "strategy" attribute?

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-odm, odm

What is strategy attribute in @EmbedOne annotation? And what is the difference between its values? set , pushAll
I not find any good explain in references about Annotation in ODM,like
[Annotations Reference](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/docs/en/reference/annotations-reference.rst) , ...

Is there a complete reference,cheat sheet,or slide about annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is likely a copy/paste error in the documentation and should be removed. The `set` and `pushAll` strategies only apply to collections (e.g. EmbedMany, ReferenceMany), and determine what update operations will be used to persist changes back to MongoDB. They are described in more detail in the [Storage Strategies](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/1.2.x/reference/storage-strategies.html) page (in addition to some other strategies).

Comment: Sorry @jmikola... i couldn't find that later. You're great. Tnx

Comment: the link is broken

Comment: @marcio: Looks like recent edits to the documentation relocated that article. I've updated the link.